# How Hive access data in Hdfs ? in Hadoop2.0

Tags: mapreduce, hive, hiveql, hadoop-yarn

I like to run the WordCount example on Hadoop2.0. I know we can do it either running java program(mapper & reducer) or using simple HiveQL.

When i write the HiveQL to run the WorCount example, my understanding is HIVE converts the SQL into MapReduce program and run example for me.

That being said, YARN architecture says that apart from running MapReduce application, now YARN allows user to non Mapreduce  applications like (HIVE,PIG,Impala etc). im not able to connect the dots here. Isnt HiveSQL a MapReduce Program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive is an abstraction program.  It converts HiveQL into code to be executed with other engines, of which MapReduce is the most popular.  You can also change the execution engine to Tez, if you're running Hortonworks, for example.

Cloudera is also planning on having HiveQL execute against Spark.  So that's 3 execution engines, all of which would operate under YARN.